# jQuery appending row and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have this javascript that I'm using to append articles to a page when a user clicks the "More" button. How can I edit the on click function to wrap all of the 21 articles within a row div, and to wrap 3 at a time within a "col-sm-12" div?

```
var buildUrl= function(offset){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    url += '?offset=' + offset

    return url;
  }

  var articleOffset = 0;
  $('.blog .load-more').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    articleOffset += 21;
    var url = buildUrl(articleOffset);

    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      dataType: "script",
      url: url,
      complete: function(){
        //$('blog .load-more a').prop('href', buildUrl(articleOffset + 21));
      }
    });
  });
```

Right now it just appends 21 `<li class="article-preview"> ... </li>` which is taken from the article, but I need it wrapped in a row and col.

Edit: ajax response

> [text, li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', li.\'article-preview\',
>   li.\'article-preview\', jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function,
>   selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the response of the AJAX call, parse it as a jQuery object, find the `.article-preview` items, loop over them, create an `html` string variable that opens the `.row` div, and then using the modulus operator (`%`) you can open and close your `.col-sm-12` items while continuing to append the `.article-preview` items' `outerHTML` to the `html` variable.

Something like this:

```
var buildUrl= function(offset){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    url += '?offset=' + offset

    return url;
}

var articleOffset = 0;
$('.blog .load-more').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    articleOffset += 21;
    var url = buildUrl(articleOffset);

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "script",
        url: url,
        success: function(response){
            var $response = $($.parseHTML(response)),
                html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">';

            $response.find('.article-preview').each(function(index, element){
                if (index > 0 && index % 3 === 0 ) {
                    html += '</div><!-- .col-sm-12 --><div class="col-sm-12">';
                }
                html += element.outerHTML;
            });
            html += '</div><!-- .col-sm-12 --></div><!-- .row -->';
            $('blog .load-more').before(html); // may want to change this.
        },
        complete: function(){
            //$('blog .load-more a').prop('href', buildUrl(articleOffset + 21));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this seems like the right approach I want, but for some reason, nothing that happens in the success block actually gets triggered. I mean the code is running (i can log the response and it's correct), but it's not actually making those changes to the page's html. any idea why?

Comment: it looks like $response.find('article-preview') can't find any of those elements. I edited my post with the response I'm getting, guessing I need to change the syntax of the '.article-preview'

Comment: Try using $response.filter('.article-preview') instead of .find()

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = yourJsonData; // Your parsed Json
var flag = 0; // A flag for adding the first Div
var whichGroup = 0; // lets us know which block of 3 items we are adding to.
$('.blog .load-more').on("click", function(e){
// Loop through the data
  $.each(data, function (index) { 
// Append the first div
  if (flag==0){
  $('#article-wrapper').append('<div id="batch-parent"></div>');
  }
flag = flag + 1;
// add a div to the parent div we just added every 3 items
  if ( index % 3 === 0 ){
  whichGroup = index;
  $('#batch-parent').append('<div class="col-sm-12" id="batch-group'+index+'"></div>');

  }
// find out the ID of the current div of 3 items and add item to it
  var currentBatch = '#batch-group'+whichGroup;
  $(currentBatch).append('<div> YOUR CONTENT</div>');

  });
});
```

Something along these lines should work if you adapt it to your setup.